# Imported Github visual studio project not running

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, github

A friend of mine made this project on his personal pc then sent it to me using Github, when running it I get the following errors:

```
SocketException: Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée.
NpgsqlException: Exception while connecting.   
InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
```

I tried investigating these errors on my own but I wasn't successful

[the GitHub link:]
https://github.com/othmanekn/MonumentsHistoriques

Comment: You did create the required databases in SQL Server and Postgesql with the desired usernames/passwords... Right?

Comment: I couldn't create it on the project, I'm guessing because there are some locks on the files that aren't allowing me to do so? so i created it separately and still same errors

Comment: Check connection string in the appsettings.json file. You can refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Have look at the `appsettings.json` file. There are two connection strings that reference local databases and I suspect you don't have those.

Either setup the databases or change the connection string to an existing database.